# DbVisualizer Error "No JVM could be found .." and "please define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME"

Tags: path, portable, jre

On [this download page](https://www.dbvis.com/download/) i downloaded `dbvisualizer.zip` and unpacked it to a folder. 
Starting the `dbvis.exe` i get this error:

```
No JVM could be found in your system. Please define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME 
to point to an installed 64-bit JDK or JRE 
or download a JRE from www.java.com.
```

#### what i have tried

This (un-)resolved [question how to solve no JVM found](http://www.dbvis.com/forum/thread.jspa?messageID=15837) points to a faq-entry that is no longer there. But i found [How do I change the Java version that DbVisualizer use](http://confluence.dbvis.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3146120) and the reommendation there is to do this:

1. In the DbVisualizer installation directory there is an .install4j directory,
2. In this directory create a file named `pref_jre.cfg` if it doesn't already exist,
3. Open the file in a text editor,
4. Add the complete path to the root directory for the Java installation you want to use. Example: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

Based on the given example path: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7` i have tried

- Option A: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre`
- Option B: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\bin`

Option A without quotes gave:

```
The JVM found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre is damaged. 
Please reinstall or define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME to point to an installed 
64-bit JDK or JRE
```

Option A with `quotes` and B with or without quotes gave the `EXE4J_JAVA_HOME` is missing error.

After closing the `JVM found is damaged` error message another error appeared:

```
The JVM could not be started. The maximum heap size (-Xmx) 
might be too large or an antivirus or firewll tool could 
block the execution.
```

#### Question

Does anyone know how i can use the dbvis.exe from the zip file (no installation) without changing the path variables of my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the answer was simple. The support had installed java 32-bit and i had downloaded dbvisualizer for the 64-bit version.

After downloading the 32-bit version it worked out of the box without any modifications on any of the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Or download the 64-bit java installation:  https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp